# How to have CSS Layout which acts like Qt Layouts

Tags: javascript, html, css, qt, layout

I use Qt for work, and a project I'm doing needs me to do a ton of styling (which just uses a CSS subset), but doing actual styling is difficult in Qt as I have to continuously recompile my C++ to check what something looks like or use the Creator, which I don't have on my local PC and makes it difficult to write and test style sheets too, to make it easier for this and future projects, I worked a little JavaScript to transform Qt UI code to HTML and CSS.

However, when I tried to implement layouts (Vertical Box, Horizontal Box, Grid), all methods I tried failed. I tried to manually set height/width based on the item's size policy, I tried using tables, I tried using flexbox CSS, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

The 4 relevant size policies Qt has:

- `Expanding` means it just takes up as much space as possible
- `Fixed` means it neither expands nor shrinks
- `Minimum` means it takes up as little space as possible to fit the content
- `Preferred` means it takes up as much space as necessary to fit into the layout

2 or more `Expanding` items get the same dimensions.
`Preferred` is equal to `Expanding` if no `Expanding` element is present, otherwise `Minimum`
`Fixed` dimensions cannot exceed the parent dimensions minus the other layout's minimum size (i.e. as big as necessary to display the content)

I use regular Qt XML, so for the HTML document they're all anonymous custom elements -  `<item>` which is just a layout item with exactly 1 child (which is a  containing a horizontal and vertical size policy), and `<layout class="...">` where ... is one of:

- QVBoxLayout (Vertical Box - `<item>`s are displayed below each other)
- QHBoxLayout (Horizontal Box - `<item>`s are displayed next to each other)
- QGridLayout (`<item>`s have a `row` and `column` property which generates a grid); When one item in a (row/column) is (vertically/horizontally) expanding, the entire (row/column) is expanding

I've only tried to implement the 2 Box Layouts, as a Grid layout would in the end just use the way Box layouts are handled (if imagining it as a table, Vertical Box is many `<tr>`s, each with 1 `<td>` and Horizontal Box is 1 `<tr>` and many `<td>`s, - Grid is then many `<tr>`s and many `<td>`s)

These are the ones I have no issues implementing are (`item.style[boxDirection] = ...`):

- `Fixed` in all circumstances: `= item["offset" + boxDirection + "px"]`
- All layout items being `Preferred`/`Expanding`/`Minimum`: `= (100 / layout.children.length) + '%'`

Both of which have seemingly always worked. For `QHBoxLayout` I've been using `float: left` (except for during the flexbox test) which has made a lot of issues on its own.

Within the generated "translated" Qt code, I use `hsizepolicy` and `vsizepolicy` attributes which then contain the lowercase policy like so:

```xml
<widget class="QWidget" name="qwControls">
  <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  ...
</widget>
```

turns into

```html
<div class="QWidget" id="qwControls" hsizepolicy="expanding" vsizepolicy="fixed" horstretch="0" verstretch="0"> 
  ...
</div>
```

A layout, as currently stands would then be similar to:

```html
<layout class="QVBoxLayout">
  <item>
    <input class="QLineEdit" ... vsizepolicy="fixed" /> 
    <!-- Line Edits by default have a vertically fixed size -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <div class="QWidget" ... vsizepolicy="expanding">...</div>
  </item>
  <item>
    <span class="QLabel" ... vsizepolicy="minimal">...</span>
  </item>
</layout>
```

I can use global styling rules (`<style>`) or set the styling programmically using JavaScript's `HTMLElement.style` map property. Anything is good, so long as in the end I can paste a Qt UI and it renders in HTML similarly to how it would in Qt (which only fails at the layouts currently)

For Qt Developers:
I do not wish to use QWebEngineView or similar, as I need to dynamically add buttons using C++ and tie their clicked signal to a specific function which accesses the underlying system. It also still only supports the subset of CSS, so in the end, I only see it being a drawback due to having to generate the HTML buttons as strings (instead of objects I can easily manipulate) and them being unable to be connected to my C++ code, though I'm happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

If there's a tool to turn HTML (i.e. `.html`) into a Qt (i.e. `.ui` or `.h`+`.cpp`) file I'd be happy to give it a shot too, as I have only found tools to do pretty much the opposite, Qt to HTML

Comment: Doing a further UI->HTML/CSS->UI abstraction layer for styling seems extremely and unnecessarily painful, especially if it's only done for styling purposes, for which layout managers have absolutely nothing to do: you're fundamentally creating a problem that is more complex than the actual one. Also, unless you have proper and extended knowledge about the UI format, you may end up with much terrible issues than those you wanted to solve. Why don't you just provide some "console" window with a basic plain text editor which you can eventually activate and use to edit and update the current QSS?

Comment: @musicamante but I'm not translating it back to UI. I'm only doing it one way, as I can use the existing UI code thats getting translated directly in Qt afterwards. Also the issue with the QSS/UI is that I need to compile it to use it, so just making a console window will have the exact issue I'm trying to solve - not having to constantly compile the same thing a million times. The layout management is also still an issue within the HTML/CSS as otherwise the UI will look completely different since the UIs use absolute positioning only in non-resizable programs

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your explanation, so please help me on that. You take a UI (xml) file, convert it to a HTML+CSS abstraction to "ease up" styling. What happens then? You started your question talking about "a ton of styling", but in the world of Qt widgets, styling has absolutely nothing to do with layout management (except for limited capabilities for subcontrol geometries and alignments); if you *are* talking about QSS styling, then my suggestion is still valid: the editor would only use and affect the QSS of the widgets/app (not the widget structure), and that *can* be done at runtime.

Comment: @musicamante I didn't know that, it very much looked like I'd need to apply it to the UI file, which then gets compiled, and then have to compile everything again, but it still something I'd need to heavily look into as a QSS - given the application will dynamically update constantly - might give me performance issues after a while, anything you can tell me about that?

Comment: If you need that "ton of styling" and you need to allow easy editing of widget appearance (QSS), then a common solution is to completely avoid any QSS in the UI files at all, and only set the QSS based on external files, so that you don't need to continuously rebuild the whole program just to change a few things. Note that while every widget could have its own QSS set, for programs with complex UIs (especially when the UI is dynamic) it's normally better to set a unique QApplication style sheet, properly using type selectors. You can eventually style specific UI files if they need special »

Comment: » treatment due to their QSS complexity, but it's generally not required (and having completely different looking UI elements isn't a good idea from the UX perspective). Note that setting stylesheets at runtime won't affect performance more than using UI based QSS; remember that even if the UI is "built into" the program as compiled code, every single element is still *created* at runtime by `setupUi()`: the compiled UI is in reality just a function (`setupUi()`) that creates widgets when it's called, and if any of them has a QSS specified, then it just calls the widget's `setStyleSheet()`. »

Comment: » Doing `setStyleSheet()` dynamically or with a built-in UI is completely identical. It may take a few moments (but normally less than 50-100ms) if applied to a UI has many elements and the QSS is complex, but once all widgets are "repolished" they will behave exactly in the same way. That's why I suggested you a "debug QSS console": a separate window showing the (current?) QApplication QSS, so that you can easily edit and apply it without even having to restart the program, while seeing results in the whole UI, including elements that have been created dynamically.